# datetime format bug for jquery.inputmask 3.3.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

when I upgrade my `jquery.inputmask` plugin from 3.3.1 to 3.3.4, I noticed that datetime format for mask is changed.

```
// in version 3.3.1
$("#textbox").inputmask("y-m-d");
$("#textbox").inputmask("h:s");

// in version 3.3.4
$("#textbox").inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd");
$("#textbox").inputmask("hh:mm");
```

In v3.3.4, letter "m" is used for both "month" and "minute", some mask definitions are likely to cause conficts, for example

```
$("#textbox").inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"); // ERROR! can't input anything into textbox 
$("#textbox").inputmask("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm xm"); // but this works fine
```

This problem only happens in `jquery.inputmask 3.3.4`

Is it a bug? How can I make the mask `"year-month-day hour:minute"` work in my page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging into the source code, it looks like you can use `Inputmask.extendAliases` to correct the bug by adding a custom alias for your specific use case:

```js
Inputmask.extendAliases({
  "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm": {
    mask: "y-1-2 h:s",
    placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
    alias: "datetime",
    separator: "-"
  }
})

$("#textbox").inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input id="textbox" type="text">
```